# SVN pre-commit issue - cannot get argument

Tags: php, svn, pre-commit

I have the following SVN pre-commit, which suppose to connect to JIRA to check for a valid ID. I have tested the script to work when I run it on command line.

```
/usr/bin/php /var/svn/service_registry/hooks/jira-client.php $1 $2
```

However, once I start trying to use it by making a commit, it seem it is unable to get the value of $1 and $2. Is the following way correct in getting the values?

```
$cuid = $argv[1];
$cmsg = $argv[2];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Misread the instruction, $1 $2 are not uid and msg.